# Laravel Dusk loginAs not working, when using DatabaseMigration trait

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-dusk

I wrote tests with Laravel Dusk and no need to clear previous tests data in database, so everything was OK.
My problem starts when add `use DatabaseMigrations;` in **DuskTestCase.php** file to make sure all previous tests data is purged.
But the problem is the loginAs not working. so lots of my tests is fail, because my tests are redirected to application login page! 
Any help will be appreciated.

This is my test code:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Browser;

use App\Models\Brand;
use App\Models\User;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;
use Tests\Browser\Components\DashboardCategoryForm;
use Tests\DuskTestCase;

class DashboardBrandsTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    /**
     * A Dusk test example.
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws \Exception
     * @throws \Throwable
     */
    public function testBrandList()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create();

        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) use ($user) {
            $browser->loginAs($user)
                ->visitRoute('dashboard.brands.index')
                ->assertSee('‌Brands')
                ->assertSee('id')
                ->assertSee('name')
                ->assertSee('image')
                ->assertSee('updated_at')
                ->assertSee('operations');
        });
    }

    /**
     * @throws \Exception
     * @throws \Throwable
     */
    public function testCreateUpdateDeleteBrand()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create();

        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) use ($user) {
            $expectedName = 'Brand ' . $user->id;
            $expectedNameEdited = $expectedName . ' Edited';
            $expectedShortDesc = 'This is a little desc for test.';
            $expectedShortDescEdited = 'Edited desc';
            $expectedImage = __DIR__ . '/photos/test.jpg';

            $browser->loginAs($user)
                ->visitRoute('dashboard.brands.index')
                ->click('@new-category')
                ->assertRouteIs('dashboard.brands.create')
                ->within(new DashboardCategoryForm, function ($browser)
                use ($expectedName, $expectedShortDesc, $expectedImage) {
                    $browser->fillCategory(
                        $expectedName,
                        $expectedShortDesc,
                        $expectedImage
                    );
                })
                ->click('@submit')
                ->assertRouteIs('dashboard.brands.index')
                ->assertSee($expectedName);

            $latestRecord = Brand::orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->first();

            $browser
                ->click('@edit-category' . $latestRecord->id)
                ->within(new DashboardCategoryForm, function ($browser)
                use ($expectedName, $expectedShortDesc) {
                    $browser->checkCategory(
                        $expectedName,
                        $expectedShortDesc
                    );
                })
                ->within(new DashboardCategoryForm, function ($browser)
                use ($expectedNameEdited, $expectedShortDescEdited, $expectedImage) {
                    $browser->fillCategory(
                        $expectedNameEdited,
                        $expectedShortDescEdited,
                        $expectedImage
                    );
                })
                ->click('@submit')
                ->assertRouteIs('dashboard.brands.index')
                ->assertSee($expectedNameEdited)
                ->click('@edit-category' . $latestRecord->id)
                ->within(new DashboardCategoryForm, function ($browser)
                use ($expectedNameEdited, $expectedShortDescEdited) {
                    $browser->checkCategory(
                        $expectedNameEdited,
                        $expectedShortDescEdited
                    );
                })
                ->click('@submit')
                ->assertRouteIs('dashboard.brands.index')
                ->click('@delete-category' . $latestRecord->id)
                ->acceptDialog()
                ->pause(500)
                ->assertDontSee($expectedNameEdited);
        });
    }
}
```

This is my env.dusk.local:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=testing
APP_KEY=base64:EOMuHiEoMcS0YvJQq+b/bSVm0kXfJwNnNFJ7WOQwWwQ=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://site.local

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=10.5.0.7
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db_test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=secret

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=database
SESSION_DRIVER=database
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=10.5.0.9
REDIS_PASSWORD=secret
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
```

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir MySql

Comment: Do you use a separate database for your Dusk tests?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Yes,I do.

Comment: Please post your `.env.dusk.*` file.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I added to the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169027/discussion-between-jonas-staudenmeir-and-amir-h).

Answer (score 0):

As you're starting off by editing a category, that implies that you're expecting there to already be data in your database. DatabaseMigrations creates your database structure, but it doesn't seed your database, so if you're trying to login there may not be a user in your database for you to loginAs.

I found that the best way to resolve this is to add seeding at the start of each test, though this does make them pretty slow. I tried a number of ways and this was the only one I could get to work.

```
    public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->artisan('db:seed');
}
```

Comment: No, I also seed my database in setup function in DuskTestCase but the problem was solved when I use Redis as session backend. I don't know why this problem happens if I use database or file as session backend. Maybe docker makes sth wrong or what. Nevertheless I just realized that the only way it's working using Redis.